# Calling methods and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out why I have these errors.

The prompt that I am making a program based on: http://puu.sh/lv7ho/2e415d805b.png

I have gotten the majority of this program finished, I am just running into some errors that I would like to get some help on. I made separate methods for each function of the program, like printing, calculating, and gathering input.

I get errors for lines 43-45 saying 'cannot find symbol' for totalTrees, totalSeeds, and minSeeds. Then line 56 I get the same errors for all three.

This is because I have only stated them in the main method and they need to be copied. However, I am a noob and I do not know how to copy the data from getCalculate into the program. I suspect it has something to do with my return for getCalculate.

My code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TreeCalc{

public static void main(String[] args){


String[] treeTypes = new String[] {"Fir", "Pine", "Spruce"};
int[] desiredYield = new int [treeTypes.length];
double[] decayRate = new double[] {0.07, 0.12, 0.08};
desiredYield = getYield(decayRate, desiredYield, treeTypes);
getCalculate(decayRate, desiredYield, treeTypes);
printMessage(decayRate, desiredYield, treeTypes);

}

//Asks user to input # of trees for each tree type
public static int[] getYield(double[]decayRate, int[] desiredYield,   String[]treeTypes){
   int index= 0;
   for(int i=0;i < treeTypes.length;i++){
         try{
         desiredYield[index] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your desired yield for: " +treeTypes[i]));
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
       desiredYield[index]=0;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter your desired yield for "+treeTypes[i]);                  
       }if (desiredYield[index]<=0){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter your desired yield for "+treeTypes[i]);
      }else{
          index++;
    }
} 

 return desiredYield;
 }

  //Calculates totals and minimums
 public static int[] getCalculate(double[]decayRate, int[]desiredYield,   String[]treeTypes){
  int totalSeeds =0;
  int totalTrees=0;
  int minSeeds=0;      
  int index=0;
  for(int i=0; i<treeTypes.length;i++){
      minSeeds+=(desiredYield[index] * (decayRate[index]*7))+desiredYield[index];
      totalSeeds+=minSeeds;
      totalTrees+=desiredYield[index];

  }
return desiredYield;
}

 public static void printMessage(double[]decayRate, int[]desiredYield,     String[]treeTypes){
getCalculate(decayRate, desiredYield, treeTypes);

 String treeReport = "Tree Type | Minimum Seeds | Total Seeds | Total Trees ";
for(int i=0; i<treeTypes.length; i++){
  treeReport += "\n"+treeTypes[i] + " " + minSeeds + " " + totalSeeds + " " + totalTrees;
 }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, treeReport);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make those fields static and remove them from inside that method like this

```
package treecalc;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TreeCalc {

    static int totalSeeds = 0;
    static int totalTrees = 0;
    static int minSeeds = 0;
    static int index = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] treeTypes = new String[]{"Fir", "Pine", "Spruce"};
        int[] desiredYield = new int[treeTypes.length];
        double[] decayRate = new double[]{0.07, 0.12, 0.08};
        desiredYield = getYield(decayRate, desiredYield, treeTypes);
        getCalculate(decayRate, desiredYield, treeTypes);
        printMessage(decayRate, desiredYield, treeTypes);

    }

//Asks user to input # of trees for each tree type
    public static int[] getYield(double[] decayRate, int[] desiredYield, String[] treeTypes) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < treeTypes.length; i++) {
            try {
                desiredYield[index] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your desired yield for: " + treeTypes[i]));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                desiredYield[index] = 0;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter your desired yield for " + treeTypes[i]);
            }
            if (desiredYield[index] <= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter your desired yield for " + treeTypes[i]);
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }

        return desiredYield;
    }

    //Calculates totals and minimums
    public static int[] getCalculate(double[] decayRate, int[] desiredYield, String[] treeTypes) {

        for (int i = 0; i < treeTypes.length; i++) {
            minSeeds += (desiredYield[index] * (decayRate[index] * 7)) + desiredYield[index];
            totalSeeds += minSeeds;
            totalTrees += desiredYield[index];

        }
        return desiredYield;
    }

    public static void printMessage(double[] decayRate, int[] desiredYield, String[] treeTypes) {
        getCalculate(decayRate, desiredYield, treeTypes);

        String treeReport = "Tree Type | Minimum Seeds | Total Seeds | Total Trees ";
        for (int i = 0; i < treeTypes.length; i++) {
            treeReport += "\n" + treeTypes[i] + " " + minSeeds + " " + totalSeeds + " " + totalTrees;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, treeReport);
    }
}
```

Or you could make a class called Result for example so you could return all the values at once in `getCalculate()` like :

```
public class Result {

int[] desiredYield;
int totalSeeds;
int totalTrees;
int minSeeds =;

public Result(){

//construct a result

}

//getters and setter

}
```

And then change the return type of `getCalculate()` to Result and return a `Result` instead of just the `desiredYeilds`, then pass that Result to `printMessage()` , this way you will have access to all these values in one instance of Result

Comment: This looks really good, unfortunately I can't use static like that for this assignment..ugh,im so close. What else can I do?

Comment: We can only use one class. :(

Comment: return a new int array of [totalSeeds, totalTrees, minSeeds]. Then in print method, you can store that into an array variable, e.g.
int[] data = getCalculate(...);
data[0]; // contains the total num. of seeds
data[1]; // contains the total num. of trees
data[2]; // contains the min num. of seeds

Someone showed me this, its just that I don't know how to implement it.